# Issues with Programmatically login into Spring Security. Jsession ID comes with .undefined suffex

Tags: jboss, jsessionid

Following is the code i'm using for prog login for my application.

```
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, passWord);
            token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
            authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            LOGGER.debug("Logging in with [{}]"+ authentication.getPrincipal());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

after this a model is returned (without changing URL, i can see usename n role here). on that view, there is a form. which submits to another link with role permission same as of current user.

but when user submits the form then spring redirects it to login page and invalidate the session.

I have checked and found that jsession is is appended with .undefined (mS5YoJL3YfznQNuItNUeiLd6.undefined) and i suspect that this must be the problem.

Comment: Spring Security doesn't do anything to the session ID. It's [entirely handled by the container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#session-management). I'd suggest doing a search on "undefined" in session IDs. You'll find various Jboss-related discussions.

Comment: Thanks Luke,

I've checked it, and undefined was coming because of Jboss AS 7.1 and this whole issue was coming because I was not creating session while auto login. I have changed the code and its running perfectly. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked it, and undefined was coming because of Jboss AS 7.1 and this whole issue was coming because I was not creating session while auto login. I have changed the code and its running perfectly. Thanks for your response. –